# Timeout fetch api?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, fetch

Отправляю запрос на чужой сайт с помощью curl, на фронте с помощью api fetch я получаю ответ.

Иногда такое бывает, что ты получаешь сообщения о долгой обработки запроса (60 секунд) ну естественно, я это отключил и сам мой вопрос такой:

Можно ли на фронте как-то визуально это сообщение получить, но чтобы запрос продолжал обрабатываться?

То есть, нажал кнопку и если я не получил ответ в течении минуты, то что-то делаем.

Comment: Если таймаут запроса истек - браузер больше этим запросом не занимается.

Comment: Это понятно, а то что я уточнил "визуально" наверное тебя смущает?

Comment: Ну вы же как то получаете сообщение об ошибке таймаута? Вот в этот обработчик и можно добавить дальнейшие действия, допустим попапчик какой пользователю вывести

Comment: Ещё раз внимательно прочти. Написано же, бывает такая ошибка, но я выключил.

Comment: Мне такая ошибка нах не нужна, т.к. она останавливает запрос

Comment: Можно паралелльно с отправкой запроса запускать `setTimeout` на 60 секунд. Если запрос приходит, то останавливать таймер. В противном случае по истечении таймера отрисовать элемент с сообщением об ошибке/предупреждение.